# Spring Active Profile not being picked in logback-spring.xml

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-profiles, spring-logback

I have a logback-spring.xml as below:

```
<configuration>

<springProperty scope="context" name="ACTIVE_PROFILE" source="spring.profiles.active"/>

<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <Target>System.out</Target>
</appender>

<appender name="cust" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${ACTIVE_PROFILE}\logs\data_%d.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="custAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="cust"/>
</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="custAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>

<logger name="com.ic" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="custAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</logger>
```

This is a spring boot standalone application.
When running it like `java -jar cust.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local`.

Even though I see in logs that local profile is being set in the application but the logs are not being created under local/logs folder.
Instead new folder ACTIVE_PROFILE_IS_UNDEFINED is being created which is having logs folder generated inside it.

I am expecting that `<springProperty scope="context" name="ACTIVE_PROFILE" source="spring.profiles.active"/>`
 will store the profile passed into the ACTIVE_PROFILE and I have used same to create the folder but I am not succeeding

Comment: what spring boot version are you using?

Comment: Spring boot version is 2.1.6.Release

Answer (score 0):

not
`java -jar cust.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local`

Do this
`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local cust.jar`

order is important